# How to change Aspect Ratio in height map?

Tags: modifiers, displacement

I have a height map 2049x2049 px and want to use it on a square plane. However, the map is projected in the wrong aspect ratio, as shown in the preview. How can I change it?

[image: Hight Map / Screenshot]

Comment: How does it look when actually deforming the geometry?